# When I run a bash script that ssh's into a remote server and run a command like wget it saves on the source not the destination server?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ubuntu@$1
cd /home/ubuntu
wget google.com
```

When I run it, `./test.sh` I am ssh'd into the remote server but the `wget` command is not run unless I press **ctrl+d** and then the ssh session exits and the `index.html` file is saved to `/home/ubuntu`

How can I change this bash script so that I can save the `index.html` file on the remote server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your script does:

- Open an interactive connection to the specified host
- Wait for the connection to finish (that's why you have to hit Ctrl-D)
- Execute some commands locally

What you want is to make a script on the remote host and execute it:

```
run.sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ubuntu
wget google.com
```

And in the script on the local host:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ubuntu@$1 run.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

Just specify the command to be executed in the command line for `ssh`:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ubuntu@$1 'cd /home/ubuntu; wget google.com'
```

Comment: I like your succint way too, making a script can be overkill if you only need to run 2 commands.

Comment: @cnicutar It was exactly what I was about to comment on your answer but finally I resisted ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have the concept of bash very wrong.  Bash is not a way to create macros that do the typing for you.  Bash is a scripting language that will execute a series of commands on the local machine.  This means that it is going to run an ssh command which connects to the remote host.  Once the ssh script is done executing, bash will execute the cd and then the wget.

What you want to do is pass the commands to the remote ssh server.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ubuntu@$1 "cd /home/ubuntu; wget google.com"
```